# How to access elements in a complex object in LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript

I am using the getRelatedListRecordsBatch method to fetch 3 objects related to the account to create a summary component. I am however having a challenge processing the data returned.The image below shows the returned results(console) for the 3 objects. I am trying to read content in the first object for starters.

[image]

The first expanded records element looks like this..
[image]

In the javascript code, I was able to read the statusCode element. Following the same pattern to retrieve the **name** in the purchase history object however does not work. I am getting an error -> [Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'Name')]]

Code

```
import { LightningElement, wire, track, api } from 'lwc';
import { getRelatedListRecordsBatch } from "lightning/uiRelatedListApi";

export default class PurchaseHistoryBatch extends LightningElement {
    @api recordId;
    @track error;
    @track history;
    @track contracts;
    @track lineitems;
    @track records;

    @wire(getRelatedListRecordsBatch, {
        parentRecordId: '$recordId',
        relatedListParameters: [
            {
                relatedListId: 'Purchase_Histories__r',
                fields: ['Purchase_History__c.Id','Purchase_History__c.Name', 'Purchase_History__c.Purchase_Description__c']
            },
            {
                relatedListId: 'ServiceContracts',
                fields: ['ServiceContract.Id','ServiceContract.Name', 'ServiceContract.StartDate', 'ServiceContract.EndDate']
            },
            {
                relatedListId: 'Contract_Line_Items__r',
                fields: ['ContractLineItem.Id','ContractLineItem.PricebookEntry.Product2.Name', 'ContractLineItem.Quantity','ContractLineItem.ServiceContractId','ContractLineItem.UnitPrice']
            }
         ]
    }) allListInfo({ error, data }) {
        if (data) {
            this.records = data.records;
            console.log('Parsing ' + data.results[0].statusCode);//works
           
            console.log('PH ' + data.results[0].result.records.fields.Name.value );//doesn't work
            console.log('PH2 ' + data.results[0].result.records.fields['Name'].value );//doesn't work
            //let ph = data.results;
            //console.log('data output ' + JSON.stringify(ph));
            console.log('data: '+JSON.stringify(data));
            this.error = undefined;
        } else if (error) {
            this.error = error;
            this.records = undefined;
        }
    }

}
```

How can one process such a complex object to display the data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`records` is an array, so you need to specify the index of the array item you want to reference.

Instead of this...

```js
data.results[0].result.records.fields.Name.value
```

...try this...

```js
data.results[0].result.records[0].fields.Name.value
```

Comment: Awesome! That worked! Thank you so much!